# Vaadin: Valo-theme menu hiding/resizing

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, responsive, vaadin-valo-theme

I am trying to replicate the [Vaadin Valo theme demo](http://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/) layout - menu on the left, content on the right. I've used the [source code](https://github.com/vaadin/valo-demo/tree/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/tests/themes/valo) for this demo as a starting point, pruning out except the UI class (ValoThemeUI), ValoMenuLayout and the Tables layout, and everything looks as expected, however my version doesn't dynamically resize/hide the right hand side menu when I resize my browser window like the official demo does.

I figure I'm missing something, but looking at the demo source code, I can't see what. There has to be some scss code somewhere that defines the menu width/resize behaviour - but I can't find it.

One thing I did have to add/do differently was add the following code to ValoThemeUI, as otherwise the app doesn't run. The demo must be doing this (and maybe other key things?) elsewhere, but I can't figure out where.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = ValoThemeUI.class, productionMode = false)
public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I've answered my own question by trawling through the valo source code.

The source code for the demo, as linked, doesn't do the menu hiding/resizing shown in the live demo (also linked), but getting it to work is fairly simple (once you know how). You just need to add

```
addStyleName(ValoTheme.UI_WITH_MENU);
```

after

```
Responsive.makeResponsive(this);
```

in the init() method of ValoThemeUI.

Comment: Yeah, the source link is the deprecated repo. I wondered why it even exists yet. The deprecation notice displays on page https://github.com/vaadin/valo-demo.